# Why i dont get an answer from my Host in Icinga?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, network-monitoring, icinga

[(Bild)No Answer from Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeIIc.png)

[(Bild)All other Services i can check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bT3z.png)

```
  apply Service "load" {
   import "generic-service"
   check_command = "load"
   if (host.name != NodeName){
    command_endpoint = host.name}
   assign where host.name == NodeName
   assign where host.vars.os == "Linux" && host.vars.zone == "Cluster"
```

When checking the Icinga service runs on the targethost I have done it exactly the same, only that I get here a result back but not with "load".

```
apply Service "icinga" {
  import "30-mins"
  check_command = "icinga"
  assign where host.name == NodeName
  assign where host.vars.os == "Linux" && host.vars.zone == "Cluster"
```

Comment: StackOverflow.com is English only.

Comment: Oh Sorry. Maybe you can help me. When checking the Icinga service which runs on the target host I have done it exactly the same, only that I get here a result back but not with "load".

Comment: Please translate your question to English (there's an "edit" link below it), otherwise it will be closed and deleted.

Comment: ok, i translated it.